# Something which clearly shows the signs of previous work done on it

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word for *Something which clearly shows traces of previous works, or work done by different approaches on it*. Or *something on which many people have worked and traces of each individuals work is clearly visible*.

I used to know this word, but it just slipped off my mind. I need to use it somewhere and can't get hold of it. It's quite a 'complex' word. And though it means "signs of previous work / work done by different people", there is a definite negative connotation.

Comment: [obviously] patched?

Comment: No, its a quite complex word.

Comment: You possibly want

**eclectic**

ADJECTIVE

1 deriving ideas, style, or taste from a broad and diverse range of sources. [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eclectic)].  I gave this as an answer, but then discovered your question to be a duplicate if this is the case. // Ah, I see it isn't; but 'eclectic' doesn't cover the 'obviously altered' aspect.

Comment: It implies negative connotation to "signs of previous work or work done by different people"

Comment: The usual humorous descriptor is scare-quoted 'improved'.

Comment: What do you mean by "complex word?"

Comment: Its not very simple like patchy. I meant its an advanced word.

Comment: Also it has at least 3 syllables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Palimpsest](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/palimpsest?s=t)

I think I did not provide an accurate definition, or I had reminiscence of the things on which I had projected this word.

The word I was looking for was [Palimpsest](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/palimpsest?s=t). Google defines this word as

> a manuscript or piece of writing material on which later writing has been superimposed on effaced earlier writing.
>
> something reused or altered but still bearing visible traces of its earlier form. Ex. "Sultan Palace is a palimpsest of the taste of successive owners"

Comment: Which is why your question should have been tagged single-word request and you should see the note for that tag: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used." In general I don't bother with questions of this type but thought of *iteration*  while browsing.

Comment: pentimento (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentimento) may also fit.

Comment: @PaulDirac Yeah I saw Pentimento too. It kind of fits. It implies that artist (or worker) later changed their minds and created something different than what was originally thought. You should post that as an answer so that its conspicuous to future audiences.

Answer (score 1):

Given that *layer* doesn't seem "complex" and that we basically have to play a guessing game here, perhaps the not necessarily negative in connotation:

**Iteration**

> 1.1
>   Repetition of a mathematical or computational procedure applied to the result of a previous application, typically as a means of obtaining successively closer approximations to the solution of a problem.

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/iteration)

Or one of dozens of [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/iteration) including "complex"  ones such as *replication, recurrence, redundancy...*